# comparing two CDFs with different x-ranges?

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I was wondering what is an appropriate method to quantitatively compare two CDFs where the x-ranges are different. For example, lets say CDF1 has x values ranging from 0 0.5 and CDF2 has values ranging from 0.5 to 1. If you apply the Kolmogorov Smirnov two sample test, you will always get the K-S distance value to be 1. It is statistically correct to rescale the x-ranges to be comparable before doing the KS test?

Comment: You're saying you have two CDFs which are completely different and then asking how to compare them.  That raises the question of *what is this comparison intended to show*?

Comment: Consider the case of two CDFs where the CDF values are exactly the same but the xrange is shifted by a factor. I want a metric to indicate that the distributions are similar. But the different x-ranges of the CDFs in this case would cause the KS-test to say that they are different.

Comment: Your remark suggests you might be looking for something like the [Lilliefors test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test). But you do need to be more specific about what kinds of transformations you would consider acceptable. For instance, would a change of scale be OK too? How about nonlinear transformations, such as Box-Cox transformations? This gets right back to the basic issue: *why* are you making this comparison?  What exactly do you mean by "similar"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The problem I am working with is to compare the distribution of a physical variable from two different sets of data (one in satellite radiances and one in m3/m3 on the surface. A unit conversion is not trivial). I am looking for a way to quantify if the distributions of the two datasets are similar or if the conversion method to translate the data from satellite radiances to m3/m3 fundamentally changed the distribution.

Comment: Knowledge of the two measurement systems will guide you. For instance, if you are looking at responses on a 2D sensor, then you will be indifferent to changes of location and orientation (and maybe to changes of scale). Although a general answer to your question could be offered, I think it might be less of a burden on whoever answers if you could be a little more specific about this detail. Another form of answer would describe how to estimate the full change from one (1D) distribution to the next (via a probability integral transform estimated from the ECDFs); that might be even more useful.